# regex for exclude some sub folders that match with a starting string

Tags: javascript, linux

I am trying to set a regex pattern to allow parent folder with any characters(case insensitive) including special characters and exclude sub folder name whenever that match specific starting word with case insensitive.

I got temporary solution that excludes the sub folders, but in that regex i have to hard code all the sub folders that i want to exclude:

`[a-zA-Z0-9\-]\/(?!(st1|str2|str3))`

Here users able to create any name as parent folder including special characters:

```
its_MY-folder/foo
folder/bar
```

but need to restrict them whenever try to create a sub folder start with word "test" by ignoring case:

```
MY_Folder-name/test_name
MY_Folder/Test-name
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It would be useful to have some example cases

Comment: Please, be more specific, add the examples to the question and show different cases like what should be included and what shouldn't

Comment: Eg: MY_Folder-name/test_name, MY_Folder/Test-name, its_MY-folder/foo, folder/bar here 
 users able to create any name as parent folder including special characters but need to restrict them whenever try to create a sub folder start with word "test" by ignoring case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negative lookahead is only a placeholder, so you need to tell the regex parser what you want to match when there isn't the word `test`:

```
^.*\/(?!(test|Test))[^\/]+$
```

[Here is that regex tested online](https://regex101.com/r/Hq3Cgh/1)

You can see that after the negative lookahead (the `(?!(test|Test))` bit) I say I want any character that isn't a `/` and the end of line `$`, this way I ensure I'm at the end of the path.

In my regex I match the whole string, from start to end, but you can remove the `^.*` at the beginning.

The case insensitivity is usually a feature of the library you are using, so have a look on how to do it. For instance, if you use Linux and grep, you can do `grep -i` to be case insensitive.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: If you think this is answer is helpful, please upvote. If this solves your problem as best as it could be solved, please select accept the answer

Comment: But i have to ignore the case for Test string. eg: TEST,test,TEst, teST all are same, not to hardcore like "test|Test". Just i wanna something like "test /i"

Comment: That's included in my answer and it depends of your regex parser. The regex I wrote is just an example

Comment: you provided perfect answer for my query. But i need some extra stuff on that. i wanna exclude all folders inside 'test' folder not only with name 'Test' but also starts with any name  eg: any-name_here/exclude_only_test/exclude_all_folders_inside_test

Comment: hh-hh/test/test, here test folders are excluded.   hh-hh/test/dev, here dev shuld not be accessible, but now we are getting.

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/1215156/colofabrixny any update on this please.

Comment: What have you tried to adapt my answer to your probem? StackOverflow is not a community where people solve problems on demand.

Comment: You can read about good questions and how to ask a question here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17494/im-new-to-stackoverflow-what-should-i-consider-before-asking-question